# How to set a static peer IP for pppoeconf?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ppp

Some ISPs only use PPPoE for authentication and require the internet subscriber to set peer addresses manually. How do I set local and remote peer addresses if I'm using `pppoeconf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On debian-based systems (and possibly others), a configuration file for your default ppp connection should be located at `/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider`. You can specify a peer address in the following manner:

```
# assuming local peer address is `X.X.X.X` and remote peer address is `Y.Y.Y.Y`

X.X.X.X:Y.Y.Y.Y
```

You may omit either address provided that you preserve the colon. See man pppd(1) for more information.

Note that you will also need to manually specify a source address other than `X.X.X.X` for the default route if the local peer address isn't publicly routable.